# cURL PHP Website Passthrough with CookieJar

Tags: php, bash, curl

I'm writing an API for a website that contains a login. I'm using cURL to achieve this. The site requires one page to be accessed before the other can be accessed; ex: "Portal" needs to be opened before I can go to "Portal/AccountInfo". As expected when I manually script this with Bash, I get the desired output when I call /Portal/AccountInfo.

```
curl -c c.txt -d "Username=u&Password=p" https://somewebsite.com/Login
curl -b c.txt -L https://somewebsite.com/Portal/
curl -b c.txt -L https://somewebsite.com/Portal/AccountInfo/
```

Although upon translation of this to PHP using cURL I can't get the correct output of the third request. See below:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$Username = $_POST["Username"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://somewebsite.com/Login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Username=$Username&Password=$Password");
curl_exec ($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://somewebsite.com/Portal");
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://somewebsite.com/Portal/AccountInfo");
$buf3 = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

echo "<PRE>".htmlentities($buf3); //This output is not the same as the third command I wrote in bash
unlink("/tmp/cookie");
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't translated the -L into PHP code: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION and it could be what is missing.